# How can I change outcome of Middle Clicking Firefox tab?

Tags: firefox

When I click tab in Firefox with mouse's middle scroll wheel, tab closes. I want middle clicking to duplicate tab please.

Answer (score 2):

I know three other ways :-)

- middle-mouse-click the reload symbol left of your URL bar
- ctrl + leftclick the reload symbol left of your URL bar
- rightclick the tab and select `clone tab`

Otherwise I think you'll need to look into a extension

Comment: I don't have the right-click > Clone Tab option. But the other two work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to duplicate, (using no third party software), 
is to:

(1) Press the Alt+D, then release the D and press Enter while still holding Alt.

(2) Right-click on the tab and choose Duplicate or press D while right clicking.

---

(Other is third-party software)

Duplicate tabby

By Skeletonxf

Duplicates the current tab from keyboard shortcuts or when you 
click the icon

"With Firefox 57 released in 2017 a duplicate tab menu option on the tab menu was added by default. "

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate_tab/

(Please disregaurd the middlemouse.contentLoadURL, I have a bug in my 
Firefox which made it do other things...)